# Mac does not recognize iPhone when it is connected by USB

Tags: macos, iphone, mac, driver

[image]

My iPhone fails to connect to my mac via USB charger. The USB port and the cable are working. System Information shows that "unknown device (...not been configured)". I don't know why this happens?

Comment: Try connecting it to a non USB 3.0 port (into computer not into keyboard). Also is your iPhones jailbroken? Does iTunes recognize it?

Comment: No iphone is not jailbroken nor itunes recognize it. And yes i installed mac on intel chip set mother board.

Comment: Ok, try plugging it into your ocmputer ( or any non USB 3.0 port). Also, does your mouse or keyboard work in the same port? [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4635540) site might help you

Comment: Ok. Yes, At same port, mouse and keyboard is working.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is resetting the SMC. It is risky, so backup. [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) tells you how

Comment: Does your phone get recognised by another computer? Does it charge correctly from a wall charger?

Comment: All - rather than play Customer Support in the comments / 20 questions guessing game, let's see if the OP can work through the official steps to isolate the issue and ask a follow on question once they can provide enough data to get things sorted.

Comment: Try looking at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294203) for some suggestions on how to get iTunes to see your iPhone again

Answer (score 0):

Lots of reasons this could happen.

Rather than us guessing, here's the recipe for isolating the cause:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203979 - If you don't see your connected device in iTunes for Mac

Comment: The article doesn't really help one isolate the issue to a specific cause