# iphone not recognized by USB (and itunes) by macbook pro

Tags: iphone, itunes, usb

From following the steps in the official apple support page, it seems my computer is not able to recognize my iphone.

Other [similar questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189653/mac-does-not-recognize-iphone-when-it-is-connected-by-usb) show an "unknown device" of some sort, which in my case isn't there. The phone is charging, so it's somehow connected and the USB port works with my mouse for example.

I've tried what's mentioned [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203979) but it didn't work. 
Latest itunes version: 12.4.0.119
Latest IOS version: 9.3.2

**EDIT** 
After connecting an ipad, the connection worked via itunes.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: plugging a different iPhone or iPad into the MacBook?

Comment: Just tried with an ipad. After plugging it, there are no changes in the system information

Comment: If able, can you try using another computer

Comment: I don't have another one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend selling MAC products. This was my "solution". Never had any more issues.